# Why does ln -s create a directory if soft-link exists?

Tags: bash, ln

I ran this command

`ln -s /folder1/dir  /folder2/soft_link`

which did create a soft-link file where `/folder2/soft_link` pointed to `/folder1/dir`.

But I notice when I run that same command again, it then creates the file `/folder1/dir/soft_link` which points to `/folder1/dir`.

It is only when I run it a third time that it finally says that the soft-link already exists.

But if I run `ln -s /folder1/dir  /folder2/`

it will not create that unnecessary soft link of `/folder1/dir/soft_link` if I run it a second time.

Which brings me to my question. How come it creates that unnecessary directory if I don't use the `-n` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NAME
>
> ln - make links between files
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>   ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME  
>   ln [OPTION]... TARGET  
>   ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY  
>   ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...
> ```

`ln` can be called in different ways. Thus it behaves differently if the last argument is a directory. So you need `-n` or `-T` to enforce a specific behaviour.

Comment: "Thus it behaves differently if the last argument is a directory. "

But the last argument isn't a directory, it is a soft link.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Directory symlinks are treated like directories in most cases.

Comment: @modernNeo you mentioned the `-n` option, did you see its description?

Comment: @HaukeLaging `-n` is a dummy option that is always ignored and `-T` is an unsupported option so you do not seem to talk about the `UNIX` command `ln`.

Comment: @schily In a certain way I never talk about UNIX commands here. But something in the question tells me that I am talking about the same command as the questioner.

Comment: @schily Several weeks ago I wanted to contact you but I did not find our email conversation from years ago... Before the Covid-19 fun began, I was in a good position to make https://berlin.linux-presentation-day.de/ an event with so many locations that we could present additional topics at single locations (see heading "Schwerpunktstandorte").

Comment: @HaukeLaging This is a UNIX forum and I cannot see any hint in the question that the questioneer is not using UNIX.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Most of the man pages for my software contain a mail address, so getting in contact is easy. BTW: As mentioned in former times, I would support a OS neutral OSS oriented event.